# undefined method `valid?' testing with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, factory-bot

I'm performing the simplest test on the following class (inside model's folder):

```
class Offer
  attr_accessor :title, :payout, :thumbnail

  def initialize(title, payout, thumbnail)
    @title = title
    @payout = payout
    @thumbnail = thumbnail
  end
end
```

The thing is there's no 'offers' db table. The objects created out of this class are never saved in a database.

Then i perform the tests using rspec:

```
describe Offer do

  it "has a valid factory" do
    expect(FactoryGirl.create(:offer)).to be_valid
  end
    ...
end
```

and FactoryGirl:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :offer do
    skip_create
    title { Faker::Name.name }
    payout { Faker::Number.number(2) }
    thumbnail { Faker::Internet.url }

    initialize_with { new(title, payout, thumbnail)}
  end
end
```

And i get the following error:

```
> undefined method `valid?' for #<Offer:0x00000002b78958>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `Offer` class is not inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`, you're not getting any of the stuff that comes along with it (such as validations). `valid?` is a method provided through ActiveRecord's modules, not by Ruby directly, so it won't be available on a basic Ruby class.

If all you care about is validations, then you can include the `ActiveModel::Validations` module in your class and it will give you `valid?` as well as `validates_presence_of`, etc.:

```
class Offer
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  ...
end
```

You can also just `include ActiveModel` to get a couple other things such as ActiveRecord's naming and conversion benefits (as well as validation).